# Get home directory by username

Tags: linux, bash

I want to obtain home dir of any user with echo

```
echo ~puchuu
>> /home/puchuu
```

But I cant use variable

```
echo ~$USER
>> ~puchuu
echo `echo ~$USER`
>> ~puchuu
```

Comment: Please do not use `eval` or `bash -c` with a variable. I added an answer that works safely for an Linux/Unix/macOS system with bash (even if you are not using bash as your shell, it likely has bash available because bashisms are everywhere). https://superuser.com/a/1613980/3376

Answer (score 133, accepted):

You can use `eval`:

```
eval echo ~$USER
```

But see [Andrew](https://superuser.com/users/59059/andrew-macfie)'s comment and [glenn](https://superuser.com/users/4714/glenn-jackman)'s reply below.

Comment: In bash eval isn't needed it with just `echo ~$username` it's okay, but in sh eval is needed if is a variable

Comment: This sometimes gives the wrong value, maybe the home folder of a previous account with the same username?

Comment: @AndrewMacFie: What do you mean by "previous"?

Comment: @choroba Add a user, delete the user, then add a user with the same username. If the user's home folder is different the second time, this command gives the original home folder rather than the current one. glenn jackman's answer gives the current one.

Comment: Note also that if you `eval echo "~$USER"` you are making the assumption that `$USER` does not contain special characters that the shell may interpret. For example, if `USER="foo\$bar"`, then when we `eval` the shell will substitute `$bar` into your output which is not what you want. Basically, if you take this route, you need to make sure that `$USER` is sane input. Most of the time it probably will be, but you should bear this in mind.

Comment: if you want to assign it to a variable, use this: `userdir=$(eval echo ~$SOMEUSER)`

Comment: Can confirm that this won't work at all if you have anything other than letters and numbers in a username. The method provided by Evan Carroll & Glen Jackmans answer below appears to work at least on Ubuntu 18. E.g:

`$( getent passwd "john-smith" | cut -d: -f6 )`

Comment: I can't recreate @Andrew 's claim: I started bash in an ubuntu docker container with `docker run -it --rm ubuntu bash` and then ran `user=foobar; yes $'\n' | adduser --home /first $user; deluser $user; delgroup $user; yes $'\n' | adduser --home /second $user; eval echo ~$user` and got `/second` as the output.

Comment: I can't recreate @FelipeAlcacibar 's claim:  I started bash in an ubuntu docker container with `docker run -it --rm ubuntu bash` and then ran `username=news; echo ~$username` and got `~news` I then ran `username=news; eval echo ~$username` and got `/var/spool/news`

Comment: @BrunoBronosky I ignore what base image are you using in the docker, at least on mines uses a sh (BusyBox) shell, check that.

Comment: The solution of @FelipeBuccioni does not work neither in bash no in sh. It works in zsh though.

Answer (score 112):

This might work for you:

```
homedir=$( getent passwd "$USER" | cut -d: -f6 )
```

This will also work on users that are not you. For instance,

```
homedir=$( getent passwd "someotheruser" | cut -d: -f6 )
```

Comment: This is legit, using `getenv` rather than assuming the location of `passwd` is even a step further than assuming the location of home is `/home/`

Answer (score 23):

It seems you are that user -- why not

```
echo $HOME
```

?

Comment: This won't work if you are in a sudo'ed environment and did not pass sudo the -H or -i flags - $HOME will still be the previous (sudo'ing) user's home directory.

Answer (score 12):

## There is a safe way to do this!

### on Linux/BSD/macOS/OSX without sudo or root

```bsh
user=pi
user_home=$(bash -c "cd ~$(printf %q "$user") && pwd")
```

**NOTE:** The reason this is safe is because bash (even versions prior to 4.4) has its own `printf` function that includes:

> `%q   quote the argument in a way that can be reused as shell input`

See: `help printf`

#### Compare to how other answers respond to code injection

```bsh
# "ls /" is not dangerous so you can try this on your machine
# But, it could just as easily be "sudo rm -rf /*"
$ user="root; ls /"
$ printf "%q" "$user"
root\;\ ls\ /

# This is what you get when you are PROTECTED from code injection
$ user_home=$(bash -c "cd ~$(printf "%q" "$user") && pwd"); echo $user_home
bash: line 0: cd: ~root; ls /: No such file or directory

# This is what you get when you ARE NOT PROTECTED from code injection
$ user_home=$(bash -c "cd ~$user && pwd"); echo $user_home
bin boot dev etc home lib lib64 media mnt ono opt proc root run sbin srv sys tmp usr var /root

$ user_home=$(eval "echo ~$user"); echo $user_home
/root bin boot dev etc home lib lib64 media mnt ono opt proc root run sbin srv sys tmp usr var
```

### on Linux/BSD/macOS/OSX as root

If you are doing this because you are running something as `root` then you can use the power of sudo:

```bsh
user=pi
user_home=$(sudo -u "$user" sh -c 'echo $HOME')
```

### on Linux/BSD (but not modern macOS/OSX) without sudo or root

If not, the you can get it from `/etc/passwd`. There are already lots of examples of using `eval` and `getent`, so I'll give another option:

```bsh
user=pi
user_home=$(awk -v u="$user" -v FS=':' '$1==u {print $6}' /etc/passwd)
```

I would really only use that one if I had a bash script with lots of other awk oneliners and no uses of `cut`. While many people like to "code golf" to use the fewest characters to accomplish a task, I favor "tool golf" because using fewer tools gives your script a smaller "compatibility footprint". Also, it's less man pages for your coworker or future-self to have to read to make sense of it.

Comment: But `"$user"` instead of `$USER`

Comment: `cd ... && pwd` is not needed, a simple `echo` will suffice. Also, I suggest to improve quoting:  `~$(printf '%q' "$user")`

Comment: @MestreLion, will it be `user_home=$(bash -c "echo ~$(printf '%q' "$username")")` or `user_home=$(bash -c "echo ~$username")`? Which one is correct?

Comment: @Kyo Both are correct and will work if you can make sure `$username` is an actual user name, but, as explained in the answer, the `printf %q` version is safer as it protects against code injection if `$username` comes from untrusted sources

Answer (score 3):

ZSH users can place the tilde (`~`) outside the expression. This does not work on Bash:

```
echo ~`echo $USER`
```

Comment: Maybe works, but overly complicated (and archaic with the backticks). Just use `echo ~$user` or `echo ~"$user"` if you are afraid of usernames containing "funny" characters.

Answer (score 1):

Once you login, run `cd` to go to your home directory, then run `pwd` to print the working directory.

Comment: That's not going to work; the idea here is to do this in shell script, and presumably without requiring the credentials of the user in question...

Comment: -1 for the same reason SamB mentioned. I edited your answer because I want you to see how to use Markdown formatting, and to be more concise. You also missed the much easier method, which is just `echo $HOME`.

Answer (score -1):

how about using `realpath` instead of `eval`:

```
realpath ~$USER
```

because eval can execute anything, where as realpath will not.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. It just treats ~$USER as a filename in the current directory. For example if USER="bob" and PWD=/home/bob/Desktop, this expands to "/home/bob/Desktop/~bob"

Comment: ~$USER syntax only work switch the user home, problem is it doesn't expand properly when used in variable and user must be valid.

Comment: From what I can tell realpath doesn't evaluate the ~bob syntax at all. Rather, in some cases the bash shell expands it and passes the expanded result into realpath.