# command doesn't work in BASH

Tags: bash

I have a script that checks if the users home dir is there
here is the bit I'm stuck with

```
j=`su $p -c df -h | grep $p`
```

can anyone help me here?
df -h won't work but df will work...

Comment: `su $p -c "df -h" | grep $p`

Comment: This is going through a while look so no luch with this

Comment: #!/bin/bash
filename='users'

while read p; do



j=`su $p -c df -h | grep $p`


echo $j


done < $filename

Comment: j=`su $p -c "df -h" | grep $p`

Comment: It doesn't matter if it's inside a loop, the problem is that if you don't use the double quotes, bash will think the `-h` flag should be added to `su` instead of the `df` command, so simply wrap the `df -h` command within double quotes and it should work

Comment: Note that `sudo -u $p df -h` will work without quotes: after processing its options `sudo` treats the rest of its run string as the command to be executed (there is no `-c` option).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are overcomplicating this.

I'm assuming here that `$p` holds the user name for the user you are currently interested in (because you are passing it to `su`), and that you are merely interested in a yes/no answer as to whether the home directory exists.

We can take advantage of the fact that in bash, `~username` expands to the path to the home directory for `username`. This is done [in this answer](https://superuser.com/a/484280/53590) (the question has other answers pointing to other potential solutions as well):

```
eval echo ~$USER
```

We can then take advantage of the fact that `test -d` tests whether a file system name "exists and is a directory", and use subprocess substitution together with the `eval` to feed the expanded value for `~username` to it:

```
test -d $( eval echo ~"$p" ) && echo yes
```

This will execute the `echo yes` if and only if (because it follows the `&&`, which requires the preceding command to return a success status) (1) the home directory for the user named by `$p` exists (note that this isn't dependent on it having any particular location in the file system), and (2) it is a directory. The quoting ensures that this won't break should the username contain whitespace (which is valid but uncommon on Unix-like systems).

Simply replace the `echo yes` with whatever you want. I get the feeling that you just want  `$j` to be non-emtpy if the home directory exists, in which case you could do something much like (this snippet would form the body of the loop):

```
unset j
test -d $( eval echo ~"$p" ) && j=1
if test -n "$j"; then
    echo Home directory found for "$p"
else
    echo Home directory NOT found for "$p"
fi
```

(the last line would obviously be replaced by whatever specific logic you have in mind)

If you truly need the output of `df`, it shouldn't be terribly difficult to adapt the script above to provide it instead. For the time being, I'm leaving that as an exercise to the reader.

Oh, and try to use more descriptive variable names. It will help *immensely* the next time you need to make any adjustments to that script. `$p` would be much better as `$user`, for example, because `$user` actually describes what the value of that variable means.